# Collecting a percentage from buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So basically what I am trying to do is, I got this big harry potter assingment in which we have to create a user rating website from a database. What a user needs to do is put other users into harry potter houses. When the user is on the page he can click one of the 4 buttons to put someone in a house, after he clicks one button I need to show the percentage result of how many other people put that person in that house.
An example: [This is after someone already clicked one button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnBCY.png)

 Now I am trying to do the whole website with PHP but I feel like I am going to need JavaScript for that one, any ideas ?

```
 <body>
    <div class="main">
        <img src="assets/images/user_icon.png" style="width: 300px;"> 
        <br>
        <?php
        $firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
        $lastname = $_GET["familyname"];
        $gender = $_GET["gender"];

        $hostname = "localhost"; 
        $dbUser = "root"; 
        $dbPassword = "root"; 
        $dbName = "sorting hat";
        $port = 3306; 
        $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName, $port);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY Personid LIMIT 1;";
        $insertSql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname,gender) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$gender');";
        mysqli_query($conn, $insertSql);

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
                echo $row["firstname"]. "   " . $row["lastname"]. "   " . $row["gender"]. "   " .$row["description"]. "<br>" ;
                 }

         } 
       
        ?>
        <div>
        <form method="post" action="end.html">
         <ul>
            <li>
               
               
    <input type="submit" name="button"
            class="button" value="This is a Gryffondor" />
      
    <input type="submit" name="button"
            class="button" value="This is a Slytherin" />
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="button"
            class="button" value="This is a Ravenclaw" />

            <input type="submit" name="button"
            class="button" value="This is a Hufflepuff" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: that can all be done in PHP but you would lose the interactive feel you get when using ajax. However as you have shared no code nobody can offer solutions and opinions/ideas are generally off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need javascript to show the percentage of how many people are there in the house, but still you need to provide some code here for better solutions.